# Optimize saving and reading django mysql objects

Tags: python, mysql, django, optimization

I have a django app that continuously receives updates of clients and reads data from the database. I have noticed that after saving an object my application is much slower reading the database. This table is having more than 2M objects.

I am using django, python and mysql.

I have used the django debug toolbar to monitor the time it takes to process these events and this what I have seen:

```
INSERT INTO `manager_readmodel` (`timestamp`, `index`, `value`)
VALUES ('2019-04-09 15:25:56', 0, 7777) [3.00ms]
INSERT INTO `manager_readmodel` (`timestamp`, `index`, `value`)
VALUES ('2019-04-09 15:25:56', 1, 7777) [4.01ms]
INSERT INTO `manager_readmodel` (`timestamp`, `index`, `value`)
VALUES ('2019-04-09 15:25:56', 2, 7777) [0.73ms]
INSERT INTO `manager_readmodel` (`timestamp`, `index`, `value`)
VALUES ('2019-04-09 15:25:56', 3, 7777) [1.75ms]

SELECT `manager_readmodel`.`id`,
       `manager_readmodel`.`timestamp`,
       `manager_readmodel`.`index`,
       `manager_readmodel`.`value`
FROM `manager_readmodel`
WHERE `manager_readmodel`
ORDER BY `manager_readmodel`.`timestamp` DESC,
         `manager_readmodel`.`index` ASC
LIMIT 4 [451.36ms]
```

This is my code:

```
value = 1 #example
for i in xrange(1, 5):
    insert_list.append(models.ReadModel(
        timestamp=local_time,
        index=i,
        value=value
    ))
models.ReadModel.objects.bulk_create(insert_list)
#
#
#
#
readings = readings.all().order_by('-timestamp', 'index')[:4]
reading_values = []
for i, r in enumerate(readings):
    reading_values.append(r.value)
```

This is how the model is created:

```
class ReadModel(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    index = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Is this normal? Is there a way to improve this? Sometimes it can take up to 1500ms for the reading that seems way too long for this use case.

Comment: Typo:  WHERE `manager_readmodel` -- don't you need a column and something to test it against??

Comment: What do you mean with column or something to test it against? Thank you.